# Baking to UDIM's blender 3.0.1

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm making a project in blender 3.0.1, to export the model to quixle mixer I need to bake curvature, AO, and ID maps for the model. I was able to bake to a single UV map but once I created UDIMs for the model I can only bake to the first tile(1001). I have tried using Textools& Bystedts Blender Baker, but I can't figer out how to bake to the rest of the udim tiles.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7ZNLJMEn0Y&list=PLL3OEv6vd5VCoUPgYfR_DoCKBtzMmXc11&index=4 You can check this video out though it is an old version of blender. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll chech it out